# Android rolling digital time display wanted

Tags: android

I'm looking for Android code to do a digital timer display that looks like one of the standard timers that came (I think) with some HTC phones. The timer look is different than most in that it uses digits but has a mechanical scroll wheel look, as if the numbers were painted on a roller. It does not mimic an LED timer nor does it mimic a mechanic "flip" type digital timer. It may need graphic files to work.

There is code on googlesource that seems it may have what I want.  But I can't find any index that has images of the code running.  And it is not always easy (for me) to get the code running so I can see what it looks like.  Some code that looks promising is the following:

(https://android.googlesource.com/device/htc/common/)

http://st.gsmarena.com/vv/reviewsimg/htc-droid-incredible-4g-lte/sshots/gsmarena_109.jpg">Link to image</a>">

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want someone on here to code that for you? :O  You might want to head on over to craigslist instead man...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear.  I'm looking more for existing code.  I guess if HTC wrote the code though they might not be offering it for free anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

See http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

You might be able to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Edward.  It's not as elegant as the timer that came with my phone, but is better than anything else I've found on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code provided by a previous user:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 

OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener()  
{ 
   public void onClick(View v) 
   { 
      if (mStartTime == 0L)  
      { 
        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask); 
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); 
      } 
   } 
}; 

......... 

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable()  
{ 
   public void run()  
   { 
     final long start = mStartTime; 
     long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start; 
     int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000); 
     int minutes = seconds / 60; 
     seconds     = seconds % 60; 

     if (seconds < 10)  
     { 
        mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds); 
     }  
     else  
     { 
        mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);             
     } 

     mHandler.postAtTime(this,start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000)); 
   } 
};
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/559090/khawar

Comment: Thanks.  But mostly I'm looking for code that would duplicate the general look of the image I linked to.  I want (what looks like)  a rolling wheel look that displays numbers that are on the wheel.